# How to assign the string out put of previous line to a variable?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

```
x="abncd"
for i in range(0,5):
    print(x[-1-i],end="")
```

The above code is to reverse a string. How can I get the printed value assigned to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this simple code. Here, [::-1] work as reverse loop i.e. it iterate loop over x from last element to first element.

```
x = "abncd"
reverse_x = x[::-1]
print(reverse_x)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
dcnba
```

Answer (score 0):

We could try a simple approach like:

```
forward = "abncd"
reverse = ""

for character in forward:
    reverse = character + reverse

print(reverse)
```